# Generic Data Access Layer

Tags: c#, .net, database, asp.net-web-api, architecture

I want to build a generic data access layer targeting any multiple databases i.e. SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, etc, and the tricky part is that I need to also support Web Services, so my datasource can also be a Web Service. Each of the data sources have similar data but the column names are different and the return type(s) are different in the web services as well.

How can i create a generic Data access layer to target any datasource and return a generic object/list to the UI in .NET, C#.

.NET 4.5, C#, Web API, VS 2013 is what i am using.

Please suggest. Any help is greatly appreciated.

cheers

Comment: What would this data access layer do then?

Comment: As i understand your question, this DAL returns the (generic) data, to the Business Object and eventually to UI.

Comment: I'm unsure how this data access layer can be declared like anything but an interface. You have vastly different underlying implementations, and it doesn't seem like you want any particular logic here, so what is left?

Comment: Ok, i guess i have enough confused you, so let me clear the air here. As an example if I have 3 different datasources i.e. SQL Server, Oracle and Web Services. SQL Server/Oracle has a table Employee table but the column names are different and web service returns data in its own specific format i.e. with different properties. Now the DAL i wish to create should accept custom queries for SQL/Oracle and call a specific end point in case of web services and get data in a generic class EmployeeData/IList<EmployeeData> which i shall declare and use it in my UI.

Comment: I get that, but then what is the question? You can't write one class that serves data from both SQL Server and Oracle and a web service, so that dictates different underlying classes, and that's why it seems to me that all you're left with is how to declare that interface. So what is the question here?

Comment: oh ok i get what you are asking now. In case of SQL/Oracle i can have the query with alias names and build my EmployeeData/IList<EmployeeData> but how can i do it in case of Web Service? and if each of my client are using their own return types how can i alias the return types in web service?

Comment: What you mean by "each of my client"? Are you trying to create a generic data access layer capable of talking to *any* web service?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58945/discussion-between-immortal-and-lasse-v-karlsen).

Comment: @Immortal If you want to return generic data from DAL then you can return datatable from generic DAL layer. The input for generic DAL can be SQL query or stored procedure. But you need another layer to process datatable and return your presentation object.

Answer (score 0):

You are making things way too complicated in my opinion. Just create data access components for every data source type you have, and have them return business or domain entities that you define. Use the power of each data source to its fullest instead of trying to make them 'generic'.

Also, why treat a web service as a data source? It's a web service, already abstracted out. Just use it in your application layer and use its entities.

Bottom line: if it's too hard to do, then don't do it and keep it simple.

Also read http://ayende.com/blog/4567/the-false-myth-of-encapsulating-data-access-in-the-dal.